# Flutter DataTable sort icon not showing

Tags: flutter

The sort icon in a Flutter DataTable is not showing and I'm not sure if it is a bug, or if my code is wrong.

According to [DataTable (Flutter Widget of the Week)](https://youtu.be/ktTajqbhIcY?t=33) I just have to add `sortColumnIndex: 0` inside the `DataTable()`

What I expect:
[image: DataTable with sort arrow]

What I get:[image: DataTable without sort arrow]

This is the Code I'm using:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter DataTable',
      home: DataScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DataScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DataTable(
          sortColumnIndex: 0,
          sortAscending: true,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
            DataColumn(label: Text('Year')),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text('Dash')),
              DataCell(Text('2018')),
            ]),
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(Text('Gopher')),
              DataCell(Text('2009')),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I know, there was an Issue [Sort cannot be disabled on DataTable #26845](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26845) and an pull request [[DataTable] Hide arrow padding when not sorting #51667](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/51667). But even if I change to the dev channel, the sort arrow is not showing. I also tired the interactive code sample on [Flutter.dev DataTable class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)

Versions I have tested:

- Flutter 1.22.1 • channel stable
- Flutter 1.22.1 • channel beta
- Flutter 1.23.0-7.0.pre • channel dev
- Flutter 1.23.0-8.0.pre.283 • channel master

So I'm not sure if I missed something, or if it is a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you must set the funciton: `onSort`

```
class DataScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataScreenState createState() => _DataScreenState();
}

class _DataScreenState extends State<DataScreen> {
  bool ascending = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DataTable(
          sortColumnIndex: 0,
          sortAscending: ascending,
          columns: [
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Name'),
              onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                setState(() {
                  this.ascending = ascending;
                });
              },
            ),
            DataColumn(
              label: Text('Year'),
            ),
          ],
          rows: [
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text('Dash'),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text('2018'),
              ),
            ]),
            DataRow(cells: [
              DataCell(
                Text('Gopher'),
              ),
              DataCell(
                Text('2009'),
              ),
            ]),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, it seems, that the sort function can not be `null`.  Thank you for your help

Comment: How to change the arrow icon?